# Exporting Charts on server side with Highcharts and PhantomJS to make a custom PDF

Tags: java, javascript, highcharts, export, phantomjs

Hi,

I'm trying to use PhantomJS with module export.
I saw on your website that the export module should only work with Java 1.7.(message from the 22 august 2013 )

[setting-up-the-server](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/setting-up-the-server)

I' am working with Java 1.6, i'm wondering if it will works anyway ?
I'd like to know is there is another way to save my charts on server to then include them in a custom pdf.

I'm trying to use directly binary files handle with maven 3.04 in an eclipse Kepler project on MacOsX.

[arquillian-phantom-binary](https://github.com/qa/arquillian-phantom-binary)

Do you have some advices, links tutorials, that could help me ?

I've just begun the work and for instance i'm trying to print out in console the version of Phantom used without sucess.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

console.log('using PhantomJS version ' + phantom.version.major );

phantom.exit();

</script>
```

I get in console :" `Uncaught ReferenceError: phantom is not defined` "

So at this point, i'm lost.

So if i could have a hand on this, it could be really great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In general our modules are adapted to java 1.7, so I advice to check difference between two platforms and try to adapt to java 1.6.

Comment: Ok thanks. Just one more question. Is the way i'm trying to make it works is good. I mean, does i have to install arquillian-phantom-binary with maven and then just test with console to see if it's working. Is there some configuration i should before to try console.log with phantom. I'm just running for instance the app on a Tomcat7 Server whitout deploying, just inside eclipse.

Comment: Honestly Im not familair with that so I cannot answer for this question